# Replacement for rospy.time.now() in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 if I wanted to publish an Odometry msg I would use rospy.Time.now() to get the current time and publish the odom msg using that time. However, I haven't been able to find anything similar in ROS2? Does anyone know what functionality I can use to get the time for a msg I am publishing in ROS2?

```
now = rospy.Time.now()
odom = Odometry()
odom.header.frame_id = self._odom_frame
odom.header.stamp = now
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321536/replacement-for-rospy.time.now()-in-ros2?/) by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2019-04-21

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no longer a global instance of the communication library that you can rely on in rclpy.

You need to get a clock instance from your node instance.

```
my_node.get_clock().now()
```

More info on the design can be found here: https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on 2019-04-22**:
Hey tfoote thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2020-06-09**:
dont forget to add `.to_msg()` at the end.

[another helpful answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/354203/timestamp-message-ros2-python/)

**Comment by [mschickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/48984/mschickler/) on 2020-08-26**:
The .to_msg() is critical!

**Comment by [Wissem](https://answers.ros.org/users/141142/wissem/) on 2023-03-12**:
hello, is it the same for c++ ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2023-03-12**:
Yes, there's an equivalent API in rclcpp